# How to inject @produces method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, jboss, cdi

I am new to annotations.

I used @produces as following in a class for a method

```
@Produces
@Named("getCTIs")
public Map<String,TreeMap<String, List<String>>> getCTIs(){}
```

now I want to inject the above bean. For that I am doing this:

```
@Inject
private Map<String,TreeMap<String, List<String>>> cTIs;
```

but I am getting the following error message

```
No qualifying bean of type [java.util.TreeMap] found for dependency
[map with value type java.util.TreeMap]: expected at least 1 bean which
qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

I am new to the frameworks. Could you please tell me how to use the above bean if not injected. And I want to use the bean in a servlet. Thanks in Advance :)

P.S.: I don't want to change @Produces to @Bean.

Comment: Spring and cdi are 2 different things.  Which one do you use?

Comment: It seems that you mix two different frameworks, you probably use spring-mvc inside jboss. From exception,the word autowored implies your dependency injection uses spring di, but your annotations are for CDI mechanism. You must use annotations for spring di, see this article for comparison with CDI: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/spring-di-and-cdi-comparative-study/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation to register a bean.

```
@Bean
@Named("getCTIs")
public Map<String,TreeMap<String, List<String>>> getCTIs(){}
```

Then you can use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` to wire the bean.

---

The [@Produces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html) annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.

Spring MVC framework supports [Producible Media Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) as an attribute of `@RequestMapping` for controllers.

---

If you want to use `@Produces` as well then you can leave it as it is and make it a bean by using [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) and [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotations as well as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class XYZ {

     @Produces
     @Bean
     @Named("getCTIs")
     public Map<String,TreeMap<String, List<String>>> getCTIs(){...}

}
```

Read bootstrapping [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) classes via [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html)

Comment: How to use the method if i want to retain @produces annotation.

Comment: why do you need @produces annotation? What it does?

Comment: my method produces data for the client only, But i also need the same data for some java class. I am not sure can I use bean in place of produces, can I? I am sorry if all these are silly Q's I am new.  Thanks braj.

Comment: You can use both annotation on the same method. use `@Configuration` on top of the class in which this method resides.

Comment: He doesn't mean this [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html) method but I suspect this [`@Produces`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation which is quite different.